# point virtual host to different internal address

Tags: apache, webserver, virtualhost

**Updated Description**

I have a virtual host set up on the server. The setup below is working fine, when you connect to our server from an outside IP. So I can reach `http://subdomain.ourcompany.com/index.php` without any problems, as long as I am using my phone or any other external IP-address.

Now I want to also be able to reach this specific virtual host using our internal server address in the 192.168.0.0 range. So I would want to type something like `http://192.168.0.100:10002/index.php` and arrive at the same page, while I am on a machine which has the local address 192.168.0.106 for example.

**Already Tried**

I read through all documentation and related questions and tried using the Proxypass directive (not sure if I understand it correctly), I tried changing my hosts file on my local computer and I tried setting up an IP-based vhost with the internal server address (using ). The latter partly succeeded, I could access the server. But is impossible to use, since there are multiple named vhosts active and it would render them unreachable, since the specific IP precedes the wildcard *.

Here is my setup so far. Can you spot any error on my part?
For the time being any solution that would make the vhost reachable internally without messing up any other vhosts would be great as a temporary fix.

**Current Setup**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/userx/public_html
    ServerName subdomain.ourcompany.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /home/userx/public_html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:10002/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10002/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure I'm understanding what you're getting at. You've obviously got a vhost on port `80`, but how you're accessing it is unclear:

a) You're somewhere "outside" your network, and the url in your browser is

```
http://yourserver:10002/some/page/on/server
```

and you want that request transparently rewritten, so that the browser receives the page hosted at

```
http://yourserver:80/some/page/on/server
```

?

or b) the other way around?

If it's `a)`, then you've got your proxypass/vhost stuff reversed. You'd need to set up a `<VirtualHost *:10002>`, to serve up port 10002 to your external users. And then a proxypass to redirect that traffic to the equivalent `:80` site. Plus still have a port `80` vhost to handle those internally-redirected requests.

If it's `b)`, then it should be working, though you'd still need to set up a `<VirtualHost>` for port `10002`.